# Want to use ViewPager, cannot get android.support.* to be recognized?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

**EDIT** Sorry about all the pictures. I tried to give you the best idea of where I am at.

I am trying to get [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) working on my application, but it will not recognize the [`Support Library`](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading) that I downloaded in the SDK manager.

I am coding for SDK Version 10. This is a screen shot of my `SDK Manager`:

[image]

After installing the `Android Support Library` and the most recent `Tools`, I went to **Help >> Check for Updates**. After running this I receive the two pop ups shown below.

[image]

The `Problem Occured` pop up says that it can't find a repository at that site. I installed the [`Sequoyah Natice Code Support`](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php) when I first started developing this application but have never used it. I tried to re-install the package to get rid of this pop-up but it will not let me as it is already installed.

[image]
[image]

In my code I get an error when trying to `import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;`. The screen shot is below. When I hover my cursor over the `import` line, it says `The import android.support.v4 cannot be resolved.`

[image]

Comment: Right click on your project, go to `Android` then click `add support library`. I'm not at an Eclipse comp atm, so things might be different.

Comment: Wow... doing that now thanks hope it works.

Comment: Thank you. You should put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: i already do that but still same error @JuiCe

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To add the Android Support Library to an existing Android Project:

- Right click on your project
- Click `Android Tools`
- Click `Add Support Library`

That should take care of setting up the `android-support` jar so it can be used by the project.

Answer (score 5):

**For Android Studio 1.2.2**

- Right click on your project from the file hierarchy (should say "app")
- Select "Open Module Settings" from the menu
- Click on the "Dependencies" tab
- Click the plus button at the bottom
- Select "Library dependency"
- Search/Choose your desired support library
- Click OK