# MenuItemCompat cannot resolve

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

```
   package com.example.dylan.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;

public class DetailActivity extends Activity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null ) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment()).commit();
        }

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {


        private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";

        private String mForecastStr;
        public DetailFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                        .setText(mForecastStr);


            }
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);

            // Retrieve the share menu item
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

            // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
            ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                    (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

            // Attach an intent to this ShareActionProvider.  You can update this at any time,
            // like when the user selects a new piece of data they might like to share.
            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
            }
        }

        private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
            return shareIntent;
        }
    }

    }
```

This is my Detailactivity i get a error on my MenuitemCompat it says it cannot resolve symbol 'MenuitemCompat'

this is my detailfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bwq="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
       />

</menu>
```

Could anyone help me and explain to me what i  am doing wrong is is wrong

Solved: i used the second answer on this post
[Want to use ViewPager, cannot get android.support.* to be recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218519/want-to-use-viewpager-cannot-get-android-support-to-be-recognized)

Added v4,v7 and v13 libary's and with some small adjustments on my import everything worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't added this import to your Detailactivity you might get that error.

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
```

Comment: well on import android.support.v4.view. i get a unused import and on MenuItemCompat i still get cannot resolve symbol

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you add the import it to the activity where you are creating "ShareActionProvider".

Comment: i update the post i posted the hole activity now you can see i used the import jet i get the error i told you on the import and in the MenuItemCompat

Comment: Solved: i used the second answer on this post Want to use ViewPager, cannot get android.support.* to be recognized?

Added v4,v7 and v13 libary's and with some small adjustments on my import everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved: i used the second answer on this post Want to use ViewPager, cannot get android.support.* to be recognized?

Added v4,v7 and v13 libary's and with some small adjustments on my import everything worked